# Select only select boxes with at least one option selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`var $rows = $('select:selected');` doesn't work, and this gives me multiple instances of the same select box if multiple options are selected: `var $rows = $('select option:selected');`

```js
var $rows = $('select option:selected');
$rows.each(function() {
  console.log($(this).closest('select').attr('id')); // should only return 1 and 2, not 2 twice
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="1" multiple>
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select id="2" multiple>
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
</select>
<select id="3" multiple>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you please add some HTML?

Comment: @JackBashford added code snippet. Should only return row 1 and 2, not row 2 twice

Comment: `$('select').has('option:selected')`. See [`.has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/)

Comment: So when multiple boxes in the same select are selected, should it take the first one?

Comment: @Phil Well, that was easy! Thanks!!